# How can I run SQL Server Vulnerability Assessment from a SQL Job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, vulnerability-assessment

I want to run SQL Server Vulnerability Assessment from a SQL Server Agent Job. Currently, I am attempting a job with a PowerShell script and am running a command like the one below.

```
Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan -ServerInstance $(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(SRVR)) -Database AdventureWorks
```

I have confirmed that Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan is available on the SQL Server (I can run it from the PowerShell command prompt there), but when I run my job, I receive an error stating that

> The term 'Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

After looking at [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-steps-in-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017), I am wondering if SQL Agent only has a subset of PowerShell cmdlets that it can access.

How can I run the vulnerability assessment scan from a SQL Job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The articles referenced in @Kin Shah's answer helped me to come to a final solution. I had to switch from the "PowerShell" SQL Job Type to the "Operating system (CmdExec)" Type. I moved my PowerShell command into a script and referenced that using command text like the following in a SQL Job.

```
powershell.exe d:\data\dev\VulnerabilityScanTest.ps1
```

The command inside the script ended up looking like this:

```
Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan -ServerInstance "myserver\myinstance" -Database AdventureWorks
```

Answer (score 5):

You are getting that error because the module is not imported.

You have to use

```
import-module -name sqlserver  # or path to the module
```

see : [Running PowerShell in a SQL Agent Job](https://www.sqlhammer.com/running-powershell-in-a-sql-agent-job/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added this to my SQL Job and it resulted in the following error: "_The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file:  Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultKeyPropertySet is already present. Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present. Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayProperty is already present._"

Comment: see http://www.mikefal.net/2016/07/12/out-with-the-sqlps-in-with-the-sqlserver/

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this. What I gather from the articles is that sqlps is already imported and cannot be removed. As a result, you cannot also import sqlserver, which causes conflicts like the error message that I mentioned above.